# Web-to-lead - Input type for phone is text

Tags: web2lead

Please pardon the banality of this question - though I do have some small experience as a developer, salesforce is very obviously it's own environment so I would appreciate if I could draw on all of your experience.

I'm speaking in reference Salesforce Web to lead forms and the HTML generated/seemingly required by salesforce. Natively it seems salesforce sets the input field of phone to type "text".

Ideally - thought not a huge deal, the input type would be "tel" specifically for Samsung mobile.

Example from Salesforce:

```
<label for="phone">Phone</label><input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" />
```

Ideally:

```
<label for="phone">Phone</label><input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="tel" />
```

Is their some subtle detail or reason why this is so? That I am not aware of or is possibly not immediately evident?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web-to-Lead has been around since at least 2005 when I first started using Salesforce, and was likely available as early as 1999. `input type="tel"`, however, was introduced around 2010, as far as I can tell. In addition, IE11 didn't support this type properly, so nobody would have used it for generic HTML code as long as that browser had to be supported. True, there's no reason why it should be generated that way now, but I'm pretty sure Web-to-Lead hasn't been updated in forever; they likely just run regression tests on it every release and then forget about it. It's one of the oldest, stable, and reliable features in Salesforce. You could log a bug with salesforce.com, but I don't think it'd be a high priority item. You are free to change it yourself, as it's just HTML code that you can freely adapt to your purposes, so long as you don't change the `name` attributes.